# Add contact in correct systemgroup with Google Contacts API

Tags: php, google-api, google-contacts-api, atom-feed

I am trying to add contacts in "My Contacts" system group.

I can create a contact "without group" (stored in "Other Contacts")
see the code: http://pastebin.com/q0zksgM7

```
{
        $acontact_formated = '
            <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
                <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
                <gd:name>
                    <gd:givenName>'.$acontact["givenName"].'</gd:givenName>
                     <gd:familyName>'.$acontact["sn"].'</gd:familyName>
                     <gd:fullName>'.$acontact["displayName"].'</gd:fullName>
                </gd:name>
                <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" primary="true" address="'.$acontact["mail"].'" displayName="'.$acontact["displayName"].'" />
            </atom:entry>';

        $urlToSendReq = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/".$this->_account."/full/?access_token=".$this->_access_token;
        $bodyRequest = $acontact_formated;
        $headerRequest = array("Content-Type"=>"application/atom+xml", "GData-Version"=>"3.0");

        try
        {return myhttpservice::httpPost($urlToSendReq, $headerRequest, $bodyRequest);}
        catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e)
        {return $e->getMessage();}

        return "OK";
    }
```

But when I add any "group id" in the ATOM of contact creation, I get a "Bad request":
see previous code with modification: http://pastebin.com/gUCTs1K7

```
{
        $acontact_formated = '
            <atom:entry xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
                <atom:category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact"/>
                <gd:name>
                    <gd:givenName>'.$acontact["givenName"].'</gd:givenName>
                     <gd:familyName>'.$acontact["sn"].'</gd:familyName>
                     <gd:fullName>'.$acontact["displayName"].'</gd:fullName>
                </gd:name>
                <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work" primary="true" address="'.$acontact["mail"].'" displayName="'.$acontact["displayName"].'" />
                <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/'.$this->_account.'/base/'.$this->MySystemContactGroupId.'"/>
            </atom:entry>';

        $urlToSendReq = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/".$this->_account."/full/?access_token=".$this->_access_token;
        $bodyRequest = $acontact_formated;
        $headerRequest = array("Content-Type"=>"application/atom+xml", "GData-Version"=>"3.0");

        try
        {return myhttpservice::httpPost($urlToSendReq, $headerRequest, $bodyRequest);}
        catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e)
        {return $e->getMessage();}

        return "OK";
    }
```

Is it possible to create a contact directly in "My Contacts" system group, or is it necessary to create in 1st time the contact and update afterwards ?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found by myself :)

To retrieve system group URLID the only way is to set v=2 in GET REQUEST:

`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/".$this->_account."/full"?v=2&access_token=".$this->_access_token`

After you can create a Contact by adding:

`<gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted="false" href="'.$MyContactSystemGroup_urlid.'"/>`